# Calculate no of elements in a matrix

Tags: math, matrix

I am solving a problem in programming where I have a matrix and given two positions I need to find the elements in between including the elements given

So for example a matrix with 1000 rows and 1000 columns initial position is [499,499] and final position is [500,500] the number of elements are 4

I wanted to know if there is any mathematical formula that can be applied on any matrix

Comment: A programming procedure isn't really the same thing as a mathematical formula. The formal difference is that programming procedures contain if statements whilst mathematical formulae don't. You can easily enough transfer a sub-set of a matrix to another smaller matrix, the exact details vary by language.

Answer (score 1):

Well to get the number of elements it would be `(500-499+1)*(500-499+1)` or `(x2-x1+1)*(y2-y1+1)` which could be used for possible memory allocation depending on what programming language you are using. Then to access the elements of the matrix, you could create a matrix of size calculated with the values provided and return that.

```
Matrix getSubMatrix(Matrix matrix, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    // This is assuming matrixes can be created this way
    // x2-x1+1 and y2-y1+1 should provide the correct dimensions for the values
    // to be extracted from the provided matrix
    Matrix submatrix = new Matrix(x2-x1+1, y2-y1+1);

    // Now we will itterate through both dimensions of the original matrix
    // and the new matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < x2-x1+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y2-y1+1; j++) {
            // The new matrix can be accessed with i and j, but the original matrix
            // requires the offset of x1 and y1
            subMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i+x1][j+y1];
        }
    }
    return submatrix;
}
```

Note that you could also use arrays instead of Objects for the input parameters and return value. As [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42941009/6059867) did with his answer

As [SergGr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182660/serggr) pointed out the case where `x1 > x2` or `y1 > y2` to fix that and not assume that `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2`. You can replace the `x1` in the method with `min(x1,x2)`, `x2` with `max(x1,x2)` and the same for `y1 and y2`.

Comment: I think you also should cover case when `x1 < x2` but `y1 > y2` which you current formula of total number of elements and the code do not handle well.

Comment: Formulae does not look right if I have a matrix of 3 by 3 and I enter parameters  a[1][3], a[3][3]. The answer should be 7 elements but with this calculation I get only 3

Comment: `[ [1,1] , [2,1] , [3,1] ; [1,2] , [2,2] , [3,2] ; [1,3] , [2,3] , [3,3] ]` By your specifications it only prints elements with a last index of 3 because we're segmenting that original matrix into a sub-matrix of all elements with the first index from `1 to 3` with a second index of `3`. And the sub-matrix would contain a total of 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sure just do it with two `for` loops:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[1000][1000];
populateMatrix(matrix); // populate the matrix with some values, somehow

int pos_1_X = 499;
int pos_1_Y = 499;
int pos_2_X = 500;
int pos_2_Y = 500;

int numElements = 0;

for(int x = pos_1_X; x <= pos_2_X; x++) {
    for(int y = pos_1_Y; y <= pos_2_Y; y++) {
        numElements++; // increment the counter
        System.out.printf("matrix[%d][%d] = %d", x, y, matrix[x][y]); // print the element
    }
}

System.out.println("Number of elements: " + numElements);
```

Comment: I am very clear that I am not looking for a programming solution , I wanted to know if there is a mathematical expression that can be applied to calculate this on any given matrix.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question I'm sorry. :)